# Modifying OpenLayers 2 to connect to different WMS using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, openlayers-2

I have a program that runs in tomcat and uses JavaScript to access a postgreSQL database as well as Google, Yahoo, Geoserver, and Open Street Map map services through OpenLayers 2.12. I would like to modify the parameters so it will connect to a different WMS; I would like some guidance on where to start looking for these parameters, woulod they be in the OpenLayers.js?

Answer (score 1):

No, OpenLayers.js is the code for the openlayers library itself.

Somewhere your application loads a .js file that specifies the various layers and map functionality (it is also possible that this is done inline in an HTML file).  Try searching through all the files in your application for the text "new OpenLayers.Map" and whatever file contains that text is probably the script that defines all the OpenLayers data sources and whatnot.  You should be able to find a line (or several) that contains the text "new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS" which is where your WMS connection parameters are being defined.

BTW, javascript is unrelated to Java, they are totally different things.  This is a javascript question.

Comment: Thanks for the direction; I found "new openlayers.layer.osm" line but it seems to be calling the location from a variable.
   map.addLayers([osm]);
   map.cmBaseLayers.push(osm);
   map.setBaseLayer(osm);
Each new layer line has this code at its end.